# Swerve Control Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controls

Hi I am creating a hyper casual game with unity, but I have encountered a problem with the swerve control (I have also seen many git hubs but even these do not work perfectly)
I've put this in my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float lastframeposx;
    private float movefactorx;
    public float MoveFactorX => movefactorx;

    public Camera m_MainCam;

    private float speed = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject character;
    [SerializeField] private float swerveSpeed = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float maxSwerveAmount = 1f;



    // Start is called before the first frame update

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;  
        Cammina();
        /*Vector3 destra = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPointt(Input.touches[i].position);
        transform.position += Vector3.zero  destra;*/
    }



    void Cammina()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            lastframeposx = Input.mousePosition.x;
            float swerveAmount = Time.deltaTime * swerveSpeed * MoveFactorX;
            swerveAmount = Mathf.Clamp(swerveAmount, -maxSwerveAmount, maxSwerveAmount);
            transform.Translate(swerveAmount, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            movefactorx = Input.mousePosition.x - lastframeposx;
            lastframeposx = Input.mousePosition.x;
            float swerveAmount = Time.deltaTime * swerveSpeed * MoveFactorX;
            swerveAmount = Mathf.Clamp(swerveAmount, -maxSwerveAmount, maxSwerveAmount);
            transform.Translate(swerveAmount, 0, 0);
        }
        else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            movefactorx = 0f;
            float swerveAmount = Time.deltaTime * swerveSpeed * MoveFactorX;
            swerveAmount = Mathf.Clamp(swerveAmount, -maxSwerveAmount, maxSwerveAmount);
            transform.Translate(swerveAmount, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    /*void vaidoveschiacciato()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.touches[0].position);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if(hit.collider != null)
                {
                    transform.position += hit.collider.GetComponent<Transform.position> * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                }
            }
        }
    }*/



}
```

1 Problem: he don't go when the finger is
2 Problem: How do I eliminate the movement from right to left (Without making it go out of the path)

(Langauge: C#)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "he don't go when  the finger is"?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by how do I eliminate the movement from right to left? Isn't that what the script is meant to do?

Comment: i want the character goes in the point where is the finger, also i need to delimitate the movement for not going out of the plane

Comment: I will try to work on this as soon as I can, probably in the next few hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem: When you swerve, it swerves just in the direction, there is no limits on how far it goes.

How I would fix this: I would put the movement to change it through a function. This could clamp it, so the higher the distance to the center of the track, the less it swerves. Or, you can altogether check if the distance is a maximum and then stop swerving.
**Note: you can use other functions to do this** (they just have to flatten out the larger the input).

### Smooth, good looking bell curve way

For example you could use a bell curve. Look one up if you've never seen one before. It is at it's highest possible output of one, at a zero input. When it gets hiher or lower, it outputs lower to zero.

the **simplest** equation is y = i<sup>-(x<sup>2</sup>)</sup>. The lower i is (**above 1**), the wider the curve, or the larger the output is for a larger input. I made a graph [here](https://desmos.com/calculator/bdf7pd6yz6).

x can be the distance to the center of the track, so you should adjust i, so the maximum distance from the track is flat.

This output is what you should change `swerveAmount` to.
The flatter parts of the graoh is how much you will swerve when you are that distance from the center (x axis)

### Alternatively

You could just check the distance, and if it passes a certain distance don't translate it.

Let me know in the omments if there are any problems! :)

Comment: Thank you, but how i put the swerve movement where is the finger?

Comment: If you would want a full answer let me know, but you could try using cam.ScreenPointToRay(touchPosition); of course make variables cam and touchPosition, but this way you can use this to raycast where they touched. You could then swerve in the direction of the hit.position - transform.position to get the difference. If this makes sense you could do so,ething like this. If it does not make any sense, ask me to update my answer

Comment: i've tried but my solution usgin screenpointoray don't work

Comment: use a debug.drawray to find what the ray is you are using. let me know if this shows the right ray

Comment: sorry but i don't understand at 100% because i'm new in the game development

Comment: @dabafadibidi There is a function you can write called `Debug.DrawRay(ray);` type this in and see what happens. you will notice there is a line going from camera to where you touched. If this is not the case describe the line

Comment: sorry if i respond you late but i've use the ray i've writed in the comment below and after i wrote "Debug.DrawRay(ray)" but unity give me a problem: "No overload for method 'DrawRay' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: @dabafadibidi Instead, you should do `Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction);`

Comment: thank you, but for now i'm doing some other project and i don't have enough time for fix this in unity, thank you